# IF column exists UPDATE else ADD column

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Hey guys I'm having a syntax problem with mysql, I got this code atm:

```
IF (SELECT testcol FROM test) THEN (UPDATE test SET testcol = 10)
ELSE (ALTER TABLE 'test' ADD COLUMN 'testcol' INTEGER NOT NULL)
END IF
```

I used MySQL docs to write that, I would be pretty sure that would work.
I looked all over stackoverflow but looks like they are all outdated, and I can't seem to find a solution to this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Are you sure this is the logic you want?  Don't you want to update the column in both cases?

Comment: I was trying to check if the column existed, if not then create it. I understood that if you make an If statment with a select, the select would return false if the column did not exist, therefore entering the else clause and running the create column statment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not using SQL correctly.  Do not think of *columns* as something that just get added every time you need something.

If I had to guess, you need another table, where you should be adding a *row*, not a *column*.  This table can store the value that you want in `testcol` and the table would be created once.  (Alternatively, just add `testcol` to the original table when you create it.)

Of course, your problem are the single quotes.  But that is merely a syntax issue, on code that doesn't seem to be appropriate code.

Comment: I already got a table created on my script, but now I need to add a column to a table that everyone that has my script has already. If I delete the single quotes it stills gives me a syntax error. I know how to add rows. In my code I was trying to ALTER my table and add a column if the column did not exist, I could do that in sqllite but the same method doesn't work here

Comment: @FilipeAndrade . . . Add the column once to the table.  Do this once; it can be separate from the application.  You can do the update first, let it fail and then the alter, if you really need to.  I'm trying to make the point that  an application should add rows dynamically, but adding columns should be a "meta" operation.

Comment: How can I do this once in everybodys database? If I launch a new version of the script it has to check if it exists first no? If I "ALTER table ADD column" 30 times in a 10second interval what happens?

Comment: The best way is probably creating a second table instead of adding columns then right?

Comment: @FilipeAndrade . . . Add the column and catch the error if the column is already present.  That is probably the simplest method.  For one-offs with software upgrades, of course, you can add a column (and the mechanism should be part of the upgrade script).  My reaction in this question was to an on-going need to add new columns, not such a one-off.